# Building a Specific Library with Stack?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have a Haskell stack project whose cabal file is divided as follows:

```
library
  exposed-modules:
      Godot.Api
      Godot.Api.Auto
-- ...


library generate 
  exposed-modules:
      Generate
      Spec
      Types
      Types.Internal
-- ...
```

When I run `stack build` it seems to only build the first `library`, but what I want stack to do is build *just* `library generate`. How do I do this? The following doesn't seem to work:

```
stack build project-name:library:generate # doesn't seem to work
stack build project-name:lib:generate # doesn't seem to work
```

Comment: Are you using Stack 1.9.3?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, [you can't write multiple `library`s in one cabal file](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#developing-packages).
So you have to make one cabal file per library (usually make one directory per one cabal file).

Then, list them up in the stack.yaml:

```
packages:
- your-main-library
- generate
```

Then, run `stack <the-library-to-build>` to build a specific library:

```
stack build generate
```

FYI. Here's a project which contains several libraries: https://github.com/iij-ii/direct-hs